# Powershell script to get sharepoint site details

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have requirement to get all site collections in the farm with primary owner,secondary owner,classification,size and owner groups list in sharepoint 2016

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-SPWebApplication "http://xxx:xxx" | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Select URL,@{Name="Site Name"; Expression={$_.RootWeb.Title}},@{Name="Storage"; Expression={$_.usage.storage}},@{Name="Owners"; Expression{$_.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators}},owner
```

Note that we cannot get secondary owner using powershell.

Results
[image]